# Putting html into site with ssl but cant link to it using ssl?

Tags: html, ssl, iframe, https

Okay so I have this lil iframe with a animated banner in it. The iframe is calling in a banner from a html file on our site at https://westcoastvapesupply.com but when i add httpS by changing:

`src="http://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/btekbnr.html"`

to

`src="https://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/btekbnr.html"`

It does not work. It only works through using http.

What are the steps i need to take to fix this?

Here is my code:

## JS FIDDLE

Read comment discussion below. We know the problem but how do I fix it?

Comment: You have this problem, Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/btekbnr.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://animate.adobe.com/runtime/6.0.0/edge.6.0.0.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: How would i serve the js file over ssl? Could i just drop it in our root folder? Since our index.html is ssl?

Comment: Oh lol I would assume I would just host the file myself. Leme try that.

Comment: Okay I updated it to a local folder but its still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Congrats! your page is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your js path as  `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://animate.adobe.com/runtime/6.0.0/edge.6.0.0.min.js"></script>` in your **btekbnr.html**'

Comment: Ok I just did that and updated my file. But if you take a look at my js and plug in https to the link

Comment: it doesnt work still

Example: https://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/btekbnr.html

Working: http://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/btekbnr.html

I made the changes you recommended.

Comment: I saw your btekbnr.html code in developer console, it is still "http", you can verify it

Comment: yeah i was playing with it back and forth. Thats prob why. I got it to work with your instructions eventually.

Thanks!